# Differences and benefits on using Karto or GMapping SLAM

Tags: slam, navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Both methods look quite similar looking at the ros.org documentation.

Gmapping seems to have a better ROS support and documentation but beyond of this, does anyone have experienced or know the benefits of using each one of them in terms of performance, result quality, etc?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54358/differences-and-benefits-on-using-karto-or-gmapping-slam/) by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2982 on 2013-02-05

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been testing it for some days, and in the moment it sounds to me to be a faster algorithm. The presition sound similar to me by the moment.

I think that there are not much people using karto because the current package is broken. Here I provided a solution about how to build it:
http://answers.ros.org/question/12370/why-doesnt-the-karto-package-build/?answer=54369#post-id-54369

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) with karma: 2982 on 2013-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevej_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/24516/stevej_80/) on 2016-03-08**:
Hi Pablo, could you please check my slam_karto question [Here](http://answers.ros.org/question/228346/error-launching-slam-karto-on-indigo/) I posted it for a couple of days without any luck, if you have time to help it'd be great... thank you!